# MDTabs | AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tab_item'

Tags: python, kivymd

Good day,

I would like to have tabs in my screen class. When I follow the code from the documentation step by step, it works!

https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/tabs/
KivyMD 2.0.1.dev0 documentation:

Here theire code

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.tab import (
    MDTabsItemIcon,
    MDTabsItemText,
    MDTabsItem,
)

KV = '''
MDScreen:
    md_bg_color: self.theme_cls.backgroundColor

    MDTabsPrimary:
        id: tabs
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        size_hint_x: .6

        MDDivider:

        MDTabsCarousel:
            id: related_content_container
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(320)
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def on_start(self):
        super().on_start()
        for tab_icon, tab_name in {
            "airplane": "Flights",
            "treasure-chest": "Trips",
            "compass-outline": "Explore",
        }.items():
            self.root.ids.tabs.add_widget(
                MDTabsItem(
                    MDTabsItemIcon(
                        icon=tab_icon,
                    ),
                    MDTabsItemText(
                        text=tab_name,
                    ),
                )
            )
            self.root.ids.related_content_container.add_widget(
                MDLabel(
                    text=tab_name,
                    halign="center",
                )
            )
            self.root.ids.tabs.switch_tab(icon="airplane")

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Olive"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Example().run()
```

But when I integrate this into my app like this:

app.py:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.tab import (
    MDTabsItemIcon,
    MDTabsItemText,
    MDTabsItem,
)

class OhterScreen1(Screen):

class OhterScreen2 (Screen):

class OhterScreen3(Screen):

class OhterScreen4(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(OhterScreen4, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_enter(self):
        #super().on_start()
        for tab_icon, tab_name in {
            "airplane": "Flights",
            "treasure-chest": "Trips",
            "compass-outline": "Explore",
        }.items():
            self.ids.tabs.add_widget(
                MDTabsItem(
                    MDTabsItemIcon(
                        icon=tab_icon,
                    ),
                    MDTabsItemText(
                        text=tab_name,
                    ),
                )
            )
            self.ids.related_content_container.add_widget(
                MDLabel(
                    text=tab_name,
                    halign="center",
                )
            )
        self.ids.tabs.switch_tab(icon="airplane")


class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'app one'
        #self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        # Rest of the code


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

The .kv file:

```
<OhterScreen4>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        # Background Collor

        MDTopAppBar:
            type: "small"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(56)
            theme_bg_color: 'Custom'
            md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 1

            # Ohter code ...

        ScrollView:
            bar_width: 0  # Verberg de schuifbalken

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height

                # Voeg hier al je andere widgets toe
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Hey there,"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: "48dp"
                    halign: "center"
                    valign: "middle"

                Widget:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: '50dp'  # Voeg 10dp ruimte toe


                MDTabsPrimary:
                    id: tabs
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    size_hint_x: .6

                    MDDivider:

                    MDTabsCarousel:
                        id: related_content_container
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: dp(320)
```

I change on_start to on_enter. I remove the line: super().on_start() end i remove the root in some part. That was the error i get before. But then:

Than i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\<location>\app.py", line 1227, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 956, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 339, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 379, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 733, in tick
     self.post_idle(ts, self.idle())
   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 776, in post_idle
     self._process_events()
   File "kivy\\_clock.pyx", line 620, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\\_clock.pyx", line 653, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\\_clock.pyx", line 649, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\\_clock.pyx", line 218, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\tab\tab.py", line 1241, in <lambda>
     lambda x: self._tabs_carousel.current_slide.tab_item.dispatch(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tab_item'
```

What can i do to get it works.

Als i have 1 small other question, how kan i add a MDTextField to one of the tabs?

Thank you in advange.

I have been working on this issue for almost 2 weeks.

I have followed up on the first 20 resources I could find, but nothing seems to work or it creates other problems.

One of the things I tried was changing "def on_start(self):" to "def on_kv_start(self):", but this had the same effect as removing the "MDTabsCarousel:" part in the .kv section.